# Is it ok for an android launcher graphic is unequal in height and width?

Tags: android

The graphic that i've been given as the backgroud graphic to all my activities is unequal in height and width. eg 25*35dp. I would like to have the same grahic as the launcher icon.

these are the dimensions that i have to supply in the various drawable folders

```
LDPI - 36 x 36
MDPI - 48 x 48
HDPI - 72 x 72
XHDPI - 96 x 96
WEB - 512 x 512
```

.

how would i scale my graphic to fit each of these folders? or does not it matter if the dimensions aren't equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) for creating icons...

Answer (score 0):

To create alternative bitmap drawables for different densities, you should follow the 3:4:6:8 scaling ratio between the four generalized densities. For example, if you have a bitmap drawable that's 48x48 pixels for medium-density screen (the size for a launcher icon), all the different sizes should be:

36x36 for low-density

48x48 for medium-density

72x72 for high-density

96x96 for extra high-density

For detail :  http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html